# What is an appropriate verb to fit in all the three blanks of sentences?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

**Questions.** Below are the three sentences with "*xxx*" indicating a blank.

- They often have blazing rows but they soon *xxx* over.
- These photographs are too small: why don't you *xxx* them up a bit?
- We'll just have to stay inside and wait for the storm to *xxx* itself out.

---

**My Attempts.** I tried quite a few words such as "get" and "put" etc., but still unsuccessful.

---

**Comment.** Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Blown: a blown-over argument, a blown-up photo, a blown-out storm.  Three different senses of the same verb.

Comment: I think it fits! Thank you, genius Gary. @GaryBotnovcan